# Euler characteristic of a pair of sheaves $(E,F)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

I understand the notion of Euler characteristic of an algebraic variety $X$ (say) in terms of the dimensions of the cohomology groups of $X$.

In Huybrecht's book "The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves" he gives a definition of the Euler characteristic in terms of a pair of sheaves $(E,F)$.

The definition reads 
$$
\chi(E,F) := \sum_i (-1)^i \text{dim Ext}(E,F)
$$
But I do not understand how this is related to the topological invariant of some underlying space. Are both $E$ and $F$ over $X$? Is $F$ a subsheaf of $E$? What is going on here exactly?

Comment: Yes, $E$ and $F$ are both sheaves over $X$. It is not necessary for $F$ to be a subsheaf of $E$. The quantity $\chi(E, F)$ is more a property of the sheaves $E$ and $F$ themselves than a property of the underlying space $X$. For example, $\chi(\mathcal O_X, F) = \sum_i (-1)^{i} \dim H^i(F) = \chi(F)$ is the holomorphic Euler characteristic of the sheaf $F$.

Comment: Can we phrase something similar in terms of vector bundles. I.e. is this definition true for locally free sheaves as well and if yes why we never see it in the differential geometry course?

Comment: Locally free sheaves are examples of sheaves, so this definition works fine for them. For example, if $X = \mathbb P^1$, then $\chi(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)) = \dim H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)) - \dim H^1(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)) = 2 - 0 = 2$.

Comment: But when I write $H^i(F)$, I do **not** mean the topological cohomology of the total space of $F$. I mean the sheaf cohomology group, which is defined completely differently.

Comment: I interpret it as Chech cohomology, I think that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here $E$ and $F$ are assumed to both be sheaves on $X$ (in this context, presumably something like coherent sheaves on a complete variety $X$, so that the Exts in question are finite-dimensional and the definition makes sense).  There are no additional assumptions.  The Euler characteristic $\chi(E,F)$ is not an invariant of $X$ itself, since it depends on the choice of $E$ and $F$.  Rather, it is an invariant of the pair of sheaves $(E,F)$ on $X$.

Comment: Ok, but in what context this is useful? We are usually interested in topological invariants of $X$ and not of pairs of sheaves on $X$.

Comment: The point is not to have invariants by which to classify sheaves, but to compute the cohomology of sheaves which are geometrically meaningful.  The Euler characteristic $\chi(E,F)$ is a technical tool for relating the cohomology of two different sheaves $E$ and $F$.